# Activating Wordpress TinyMCE editor for a text area

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, textarea

I am trying to activate TinyMCE for the text area.  My code is below

```
<?php
wp_editor( '', 'content-id', array( 'textarea_name' => 'txtmessage', 'media_buttons' => false, 'tinymce_adv' => array( 'width' => '300', 'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'formatselect,forecolor,|,bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|,spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv' ) ) ); 
echo "\r\n";
echo "\r\n";
echo "\r\n --------Original Message-------- \r\n \r\n";
echo "\r\n\r\n".$reply_message_contentmain;
```

The code works.  However, my problem is that the echo message show at the bottom and outside of TinyMCE area.  Any suggestion, how to fix it?  I am not a php expert.  Thanks,

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/wordpress-tinymce_editor/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax on [wp_editor()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) is:

```
<?php wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() ); ?>
```

You've left $content blank and are echo'ing after the editor call.... so do something like:

```
$content = '\r\n\r\n\r\n--------Original Message-------- \r\n\r\n\r\n' .$reply_message_contentmain
wp_editor( $content, 'content-id', array( 'textarea_name' => 'txtmessage', 'media_buttons' => false, 'tinymce_adv' => array( 'width' => '300', 'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'formatselect,forecolor,|,bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|,spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv' ) ) );
```

This should work but I can't test it from where I am at the moment, let me know how you go (but this should put you on the right track)

Comment: Hi Cub3,  Thanks.  It works perfect.  Only one issue, instead of showing ---Original Message---- with a space before and after it i.e. \r\n\r\n\r\n--------Original Message-------- \r\n\r\n\r\n

Comment: Update following worked with line breaks inserted before and after ---Original Message ----   <code> <?php $content = '<br />--------Original Message-------- <br />' .$reply_message_contentmain;
wp_editor( $content, 'content-id', array( 'textarea_name' => 'txtmessage', 'media_buttons' => false, 'tinymce_adv' => array( 'width' => '300', 'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'formatselect,forecolor,|,bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|,spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv' ) ) ); ?>  </code>.  Many thanks to Cube3.